# Client downloading 2 images (one with and one without GET variable) PHP

Tags: php, html, image, performance

[image]

As seen on the image, client is downloading 2 versions of the same images. The PHP script that I have doesn't in any part of the script output an HTML that would be like  but only . It is also seen that initiator for image downloads for the correct images without aditional GET variable (1498980...) is "naslovnica.php" and initiator for the redundant ones is "Other". The main problem is that user, when coming for the first time to the website, is downloading both versions, but only one version is used by the HTML (the one without the GET variable). Once the user has downloaded the page and revisits, it is using normal images from his cache so everything is fine then. Currently, because of these redundant copies of the same images, page load time is around 12 seconds...

**UPDATE**

I'm using Foundation 6 and when I disable foundation.js, those reduntant images are not downloaded. Will proceed with research and hopefully this helps somebody else as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIX:**

The problem was in Foundation 6 plugin "Interchange". I downloaded Foundation 6 again without Interchange plugin included and it was all fixed. I haven't even used any functionalities of this plugin, so that was redundant anyways.